# this map would not have to revolve 2 hello?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm practicing the map function and I don't understand why it doesn't return 2 hellos, what am I doing wrong?

I have no answer, what can I be doing wrong?

```
const Books = [
  {
    img: imagen,
    title: "murakami",
    año: 2022,
    genero: "terror",
    edicion: "ivrea",
  },
  {
    img: imagen2,
    title: "Joe hill",
    año: 2022,
    genero: "aventura",
    edicion: "panini",
  },
];

function BookList() {
  return (
    <section>
      {Books.map((book) => {
        return "Hello";
      })}
    </section>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <div>{BookList}</div>;
}
```

Comment: try  BookList as a component <BookList/>

Comment: Looks to me like you'd get an error saying something like "functions are not valid as a React child" with this code...  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I got it, thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1):

BookList is a component, but you are treating it as a react node. This works fine for types that can be react nodes: strings, numbers, or other Components work fine:

```
function App() {
  const content = "hello hello";
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```

What you are actually doing is trying to make an `uncalled` function a child of a react component. This is incorrect and should result in a runtime error.

`return <div><BookList /></div>` should do the trick, the JSX `calls` your component function, which should display it.

Comment: Probably no need to have the JSX wrapped in a `div` as the returned result from the component is already in a section. So maybe just `return <BookList />`.

Comment: @Andy totally true, I was just being consistent with the question though.